# Passar data como parâmetro para função JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, html

Estou tentando passar uma data do **PHP** para um bloco **HTML** que possui uma função **JavaScript**, o problema é que ela está indo em formato numérico, como posso resolver isso?

Parte da string **HTML** que está sendo montada:

```
$tabelaDados = "<tr><td scope='row'>'.$idDesp.'</td><td class='td-centro'><a href='#'><i class='far fa-edit'></i></a><span> </span><a href='#' onclick='apagaRegistro('.$idDesp.','.$mesAnoRef.' )'><i class='fas fa-trash-alt'></i></a></td>"
```

Quando a minha função `apagaRegistro` é chamada, o valor do segundo parâmetro vem como **0.0003984938487854787**, apenas um exemplo.

Comment: Tente colocar assim no seu `onclick`: `apagaRegistro(\'' . $idDesp . '\', \'' . $mesAnoRef . '\')`. Você está passando sem apóstrofo ou aspas. Pode ser esse o problema.

Comment: @PauloImon, deu certinho. Eu devo ter fugido da aula aqui, mas qual a lógica desta formatação?

Comment: É o princípio de declaração de *strings*. Sempre será feito com aspas ou apóstrofos. Quando você passa por parâmetro para sua função do **JavaScript** sem utilizar esse formato, ele irá interpretar como *Number*. A *backslash* `\'` é apenas para escapar o apóstrofo nesse caso, pois sem ela daria problema na sintaxe do seu código **PHP**.

Comment: É... realmente faltei a aula...rs. Muito obrigado!!!